# Windows 8 Socket communication with Background Task

Tags: windows-8

I have a Background Task written in C# in a Windows 8 App, and I'm having trouble connecting it to my UI task.  I've tried opening a StreamSocketListener on my background task and a StreamSocket to connect to it on my UI task, as well as the other way around.  If I have both the listener and the connector in the UI task, or the background task, everything works fine.  However, there seems to be some kind of isolation enforced between the two of them.

I can also connect out to external services on both of them, so I thought it might have something to do with needing a loopback exemption, but that doesn't seem to be the case either, as opening up the AppContainer Loopback Exemption Utility shows all apps as having loopback access.

Is there something else I need to enable to get network communication between these two parts of my app working properly?  I have enabled the Private Networks (Client and Server) capabilities in my package manifest, (the other client/server pairs don't help, so i'm just using that one)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the completion event of your background task and run it repeatedly in your UI. Using LocalSettings to pass data.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977055.aspx

```
private void OnCompleted(IBackgroundTaskRegistration task, BackgroundTaskCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    var settings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
    var key = task.TaskId.ToString();
    var message = settings.Values[key].ToString();
    UpdateUIExampleMethod(message);
}
```

Comment: This has two major downsides:
1) I cannot communicate large data structures without writing out to a file (e.g. anything larger than 8K)
2) I cannot have a frequent background task.  By "frequent background task" I mean something like a background task that runs every 10 seconds, etc.... I am currently doing this by using a ThreadingPool timer, and it works great, I just need a way to communicate back to the UI Thread.  You can even use the Progress event, but again, I'd like to communicate more complex data.

Comment: @staticfloat - Yep LocalSettings values can only be 8K in size (enough for some JSON serialized data but by no means a lot. You should provide your code for your task creation and client/server socket streams, because as long as the background task is part of the same process it should be able to make a stream connection to a localhost server.

Comment: I think this is exactly my problem.  Background tasks are not run inside the same process.  They are run on a backgroundTaskHost.exe process.  I will change my code to use a ControlChannelTrigger, so I can run it within the same process housing, and see if that works better!